# Passar valor de uma variável em Array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho a seguinte variável:

```
var prodadicional = $(this).attr('data-adicionais');
```

Ela retorna dois valores do tipo string que são: Hambúrguer e Bacon.
Como que eu faço para colocá-las dentro de um `array`?

Eu tentei passar dentro do `array` e contar com `length` mas só retorna o valor 1, sendo que tem dois valores.

```
var dadosarrayAdicional = [prodadicional];
var teste = prodadicional.length;
```

Comment: Ele já não te retorna em um array? Quando você dá um `alert(prodadicional)` ou `console.log(prodadicional)` ele te retorna o que?

Comment: Se eu colocar   var teste = dadosarrayAdicional.length; ele retorna o valor 1. Mas tem 2 valores.

Comment: Dê um console.log(prodadicional ) e disponibilize o resultado por favor.

Comment: Se eu por prodadicional.length ele retorna (16)

Comment: Voce esta colocando um array dentro de outro array, logo o count do primeiro Array é de fato 1, mas dentro desse array tem 2 elementos..

Comment: tentou usar o JSON.stringify()?

Comment: A pergunta não está muito clara Felipe, tente colocar algum exemplo verificavel e/ou esclarecer melhor as entradas e saídas - como está o máximo que vai conseguir serão palpites.

Comment: Se você recebe uma string, você tem de tranforma-la em array antes, caso sua string seja mesmo "Hambúrguer e Bacon", receba como var prodadicional = $(this).attr('data-adicionais').split("e");

Comment: Se eu der um console.log(prodadicional) ele retorna o valor em string. Hambúrguer e Bacon. Eu quero que ele coloque estes valores da variável em um array e conte a quantidade de itens logo em seguida para poder fazer um for e listar os dados em cada LI. Tipo Hambúrguer ficaria em uma LI e Bacon em outra. Só que se eu der um dadosArrayAdicional.length ele retorna 1.

Comment: Ele retorna uma string `"Hambúrguer e Bacon"` ou `[{"lanche":"Hambúrguer","lanche":"Bacon"}]` ou como?

Comment: String Hambúrger e Bacon.

Comment: Então faz como o @FelipeDuarte disse: separar a string com split ai vai se tornar array, a partir já dá pra você fazer o que quer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Se está vindo como string você pode fazer de dois jeitos que são a mesma coisa:
```

```js
$('.btn-comida').on('click',function(){
  var prodadicional = $(this).data('adicionais').split(' e ');
  $('#total').val(prodadicional.length);
  var ul = $('ul');
  ul.append('<li>'+prodadicional[0]+'</li>');
  ul.append('<li>'+prodadicional[1]+'</li>');
  
})
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>

<div class="form-group">
 
  <button class="btn btn-primary btn-comida" data-adicionais="Hambúrguer e Bacon">Hambúrguer e Bacon</button>  
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="total">Total de itens</label>
  <input class="form-control col-lg-1" id="total"> 
</div>



<ul>
</ul>
```

> Ou

```js
$('.btn-comida').on('click', function(){
  var prodadicional = $(this).data('adicionais').split(' e ');
  $('#total').val(prodadicional.length);
  $.each(prodadicional, function(i, prod){
     
      var li = "<li>"+ prodadicional[i] + '</li>';
      $('ul').append(li);
  })
})
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>

<div class="form-group">
 
  <button class="btn btn-primary btn-comida" data-adicionais="Hambúrguer e Bacon">Hambúrguer e Bacon</button>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="total">Total de itens</label>
  <input class="form-control col-lg-1" id="total"> 
</div>
<ul>
</ul>
```